# Running two videos with OpenCV python with multi threading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading, video-capture

I am trying to run on python using openCV two functions at the same time. One function is supposed to show local video and the other should show frames from my webcam. When running the code below, the two windows freezes and blacks out. I am running it on Ubuntu 16.04

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

def webcam_video(): 

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
      cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else :
        break
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def local_video(): 
  path = "video-1.mp4"
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
  while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
     cv2.imshow('frame_2',frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else :
        break     
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

t1= Thread(target = webcam_video)
t2= Thread(target = local_video)

t1.start() 
t2.start()
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do `cv2.waitKey()` and `imshow()` in 2 different threads. I think you'd need to have a single thread doing display and waiting for keys. You can, as nathancy shows, acquire in multiple threads.

Comment: @nathancy, Thanks for you answer, I create two objects, and I was able to run both videos together. However, I wanted to show them in two different windows as they are running right now in the same window. Forgive me as I am quite of a beginner in python and OpenCV

Comment: I think you can have 2 windows, but you can't have 2 `waitKey()` calls from different threads. You can keep capturing video in 2 threads without problem. It's just that you must display the images and do the `waitKey()` in the **main** thread... https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/134

Comment: Make sure that you have two different show frames, for instance: `cv2.imshow('frame_1',frame1)` and `cv2.imshow('frame_2',frame2)`. That will probably let you show two windows while you are capturing video in each individual thread

Comment: @nathancy, I tried to do it, but I did not know where to define frame1 and frame2

Comment: You can define a new class variable like `self.id = 'thread_1'` and `self.id = 'thread_2'` (maybe pass the id as an argument to the object) then when you show the image you can do `cv2.imshow(self.id,frame1)` or `cv2.imshow(self.id,frame2)`

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to fix my code to run the video and the webcam. However, the whole point of doing a thread is for the code to continue execution while showing  both videos. As for now, it is stuck on showing both videos, and the remaining code is not executed.

Comment: Is it possible to get a sample code to display in main. I tried using queue for frames and showing in main thread but it did not work

Comment: Those frames are incompatible each other. You should use external webcam or droidcam. https://www.github.com/KadirTaban/OpenCv_MultiThreading/tree/master/src%2Fproject_mutlithreading.py

Answer (score 2):

Using Multiprocessing works for me!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Process

def webcam_video(): 

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
      cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else :
        break
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def local_video(): 
  path = r"C:\Users\bernad.peter\Downloads\Singapore Port.mp4"
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
  while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
     cv2.imshow('frame_2',frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    else :
        break     
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1= Process(target = local_video)
    p2= Process(target = webcam_video)
    p1.start() 
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```